# There is a crackling sound each time I mute or unmute the sound

Tags: 11.04, sound

Sound otherwise is fine but there is a crackling sound when I mute or unmute the sound, also when a video player stops or starts playing a movie, or when any application using sound stops or starts - there is always this annoying crackling sound, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is something in your audio chain that is incorrectly (de)activated when sounds starts or stops, you should try to reinstall the audio related drivers as well as programs like ALSA. When such options don't help, [use this page as a troubleshoot guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting).

*I've recently fixed such a problem on Windows, so it should be fixable in a similar way on Ubuntu.*